# Array of callbacks, finding position

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, indexof

How can I keep track of a callback's position in an array so that I may fire the next?

**My requirement is that this needs to be ES5 capable.**

Given a hypothetical array of callbacks, I need to find out which index it's at. The issue is that same callback may be duplicated.

Using an index number is non-optimal, as callbacks may be called multiple times at varying speeds.

**I'm essentially looking for a way to follow a path regardless of when the callback was called and how many times.**

*Example:*

```
let callbacks = [CB1, CB2, CB3, CB1, CB3, CB2]
```

If `CB3` is called, I expect it to iterate to the next in the list and not backwards (i.e. following the path of insertion).

*Example:*

```
CB3 -> CB1 -> CB3 -> CB2
```

It should be noted that `CB3` is ONLY in charge of calling `CB1`, and `CB1` is in charge of calling it's next in the list.

*Better Example:*

```
CB3 -> CB1
CB1 -> CB3 (2)
CB3 (2) -> CB2
```

If `CB3` is the second in the list, it should not follow the same path as the first `CB3` in the list.

**Example:**

```
CB3 (2) -> CB2
```

Another gentleman had commented that this reminds him of the Express middleware, and I had said that it's very similar indeed.

Comment: Please try a better explanation of your task.

Comment: I did, I want to follow a given path of callbacks in the order that they are called. How can I be more clear? Edited to clarify the important sentence.

Comment: What do you mean by "*follow*"?

Comment: To go to the next in the list. I hadn't assumed that "following a path" was unclear to most.

Comment: Then why not to keep the index in a global variable?

Comment: Because of callbacks being called multiple times out of order. I explained that in the "non-optimal" section.

Comment: Because I can't be in control of each callback's execution. That has to be done by the callbacks themselves.

Comment: This seems like a case of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Unfortunately I've lost faith in most developers to actually help me solve issues rather than try to tell me I'm doing it the wrong way. I REALLY don't know how I can explain my higher overview problems more effectively. THIS is the solution that I need, and I need help without explaining my entire application logic.

Comment: can you add an example, what you want to get, if the first `CB3` is called?

Comment: CB3 -> CB1 -> CB3 -> CB2. Essentially going to the next in the list.

Comment: This somehow reminds me of the express middlewares, where each middleware has a `next` param to call the next middleware. But i don't understand the problem/solution.

Comment: Very good point. It's very similar to the Express middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a factory function and binding the function's callback.

Example:

```
var CB1 = function(cb){ cb('CB1') }
var CB2 = function(cb){ cb('CB2') }
var CB3 = function(cb){ cb('CB3') }

var callbacks = [CB1, CB2, CB3, CB1, CB3, CB2]
let cbs = []

// Factory function that returns a new function
function factory(fn) {
  const newFn = function newFn() { return fn.apply(this, arguments) }
  return newFn
}

// Callback to pass into CB
let out = function(i, data){
  console.log(i, data)

  i++
  if (cbs[i])
    cbs[i].call(cbs[i], cbs[i].out)
}

// Loop through callbacks and create a new array with bound out functions
for (let i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
  let cb = new factory(callbacks[i])
  cb.out = out.bind(cb, i)
  cbs.push(cb)
}

// And to demonstrate
function start(atI) {
  cbs[atI].call(cbs[atI], cbs[atI].out)
}

start(3)
> 3 'CB1'
> 4 'CB3'
> 5 'CB2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) by implementing [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) in [`Array#[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator), and iterate it over until no further elements are available.

```js
var CB1 = () => console.log('CB1'),
    CB2 = () => console.log('CB2'),
    CB3 = () => console.log('CB3'),
    callbacks = [CB1, CB2, CB3, CB1, CB3, CB2],
    gen = callbacks[Symbol.iterator]();
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        var g = gen.next();
        if (g.done) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        g.value();
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Excellent solution! I had forgotten to clarify that this needs to be ES5 capable. Perhaps I can shim the Symbol and Generators though. Upvoting anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If the same value can appear multiple times, then there is no real way to track where in the array you are without using an index.

The only other option I can think of would be to clone the array and the shift elements off it as you went.

```js
const a = () => console.log('a');
const b = () => console.log('b');
const c = () => console.log('c');

const callbacks = [a, a, b, a, c];

const duplicate = callbacks.concat();
while (duplicate.length) {
  duplicate.shift()();
}
```

… but I'd stick to using an index.